# Variable Length Subnet Mask with two hosts

Tags: subnet

I started learning subnetting and i encountered some problem involving Variable Length Subnet Mask and which problems i encountered so far is it just specify a specific number of host per subnet but this have two. Do i just add them up? to hava one host requirement? here is the image of the problem
[image]

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) has a section that deals with that.

Comment: *VLSM* is a term from classful networking, **obsoleted in 1993**. This has all been CIDR for decades.